# How to add icons/images as indicators rather than list circles in bootstrap3 carousel slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i am trying to make  a bootstrap3 carousel slider and I want to add some images as the slide indicators instead of the list default circles.

Html Markup :

```
<div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">

            <!-- Slider Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul><!--/ Indicators end-->
</div>
```

if i add an img tag as below :

```
<div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">

            <!-- Slider Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/ooomf-com-files/wdXqHcTwSTmLuKOGz92L_Landscape.jpg">
                    </div></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul><!--/ Indicators end-->
        <div>
```

Its not showing anything. How can I achieve adding an image as the indicator rather than the

circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important thing is to override the `width` and `height`  properties on the `li` tags inside the `.carousel-indicators`.

To do so I've created an additional modifier css class called `.carousel-indicators--thumbnails` that is added to the `.carousel-indicators` `div`. This modifier class is used to override the `li`, `.active` and `.active .thumbnail` class.

```css
.carousel-indicators.carousel-indicators--thumbnails li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators.carousel-indicators--thumbnails .active {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.carousel-indicators.carousel-indicators--thumbnails .active .thumbnail {
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators--thumbnails">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/401" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/402" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400" width="800" height="400">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              Slide 1
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/401" width="800" height="400">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              Slide 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/402" width="800" height="400">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              Slide 3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```